# PowerShellでのFile Server Resource ManagerでのQuotaの有効化の方法

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShellでのFile Server Resource Managerの、既に作成されているQuotaの有効化の方法を教えてください。

無効化の方法は、以下になります。

```
Set-FsrmQuota -Path D:\folder -Disable
```

また、commandでの有効化の方法は、以下になります。

```
dirquota quota modify /path:D:\folder /status:enabled
```

色々調べてみましたが、どうしてもPowerShellでの有効化の方法が見つかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問者さんが英語版で質問して回答＆解決マークが付いています。[How to enable FSRM quota with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54878777/9014308)

Answer (score -1):

Set-FsrmQuota -Path D:\folder -Disabled:$False